# How to send a message to a running app (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, process

I have a running app called "app.js" it keeps running to do some task.

How can I let the user run another process of the app just to send a message to the current running process to tell it to do something.

```
node app.js reload
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is utilizing some sort of storage mechanism, like a database or file to queue up messages. So while one instance of app.js is running it can keep reading from the database to see if there are new messages to process.

Another solution would be to make one of the app.js instances act as a server, and have another one try to connect over TCP, and as soon as it establishes a connection start pushing messages to the client instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a message broker (RabbitMq) to notify the running process of an event and handle the message from running process.